# Ajax: '+' Symbol becomes '' when submitting the form using ajax to the spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

Whenever the *'+' symbol* is added in the text box in the jsp form and submitted using *ajax*, the + symbol is missing when seen using System.out.println() from the spring controller.i.e. a *blank space* is created in its place.

Could anyone tell me why it is happening?

For example:

When I enter

```
a + b - c
```

in the sql text box of the form(or the id text box), then it gets printed like

```
a   b - c
```

**query.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Query Insertion</title>

<!-- ajax -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addQuery() {
        var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var sql = document.getElementById("sql").value;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "text/plain",
            url : "addQueryAjax?id=" +  id + "&sql=" + sql,
            dataType : 'text',
            timeout : 100000,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            },
            done : function(e) {
                console.log("DONE");
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("addButton").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
<!-- end ajax -->
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <div style="width: 650px;">
            <form:form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
                modelAttribute="queryBean" action="addQuery">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Id</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" id="id"
                            placeholder="id" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
                            path="id" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="sql" class="col-sm-2 control-label">sql</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" id="sql"
                            placeholder="sql" required="required" path="sql" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    &nbsp;
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add"
                            onclick="addQuery();" id="addButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**AddQuery.java:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQueryAjax")
    public @ResponseBody String addQueryAjax(@ModelAttribute("queryBean") QueryBean queryBean) {
        System.out.println("In controller Method: Query Bean = " + queryBean);
        System.out.println("Id = " + queryBean.getId());
        System.out.println("sql " + queryBean.getSql());
        return "Query Added Successfully!!!";
    }
```

May I know what the reason is for this behavior?

Comment: @BalusC You have marked this question as duplicate linking it to another question. I am not able to figure out why. Could you at least give a hint as to where the correction needs to be done in this code?

Comment: Duplicates is about answers, not questions. Ignore the question and read the accepted answer to that question.